# how do I get statistic of ram and cpu utilization when android app run

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I was reading about `onpause()`, `onresume()` methods in Android api. I was thinking whether I have an option to measure ram and cpu utilization realtime?

Then, I think that I will be able to improve quality application. If there is a tool or workaround, please let me know. IF I can manage with Eclipse ID that will be great as I always use eclipse for developing.

Comment: You can refer [this link][1]. I suppose it will help you do your job.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5560634/1627599

Comment: Check this two solutions [link1][1] and 
[link2][2] it may help you.
Thanks

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11739444/how-to-get-usage-of-each-cpu-core-on-android
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467579/how-to-get-cpu-usage-statistics-on-android

Answer (score 0):

You can use DDMS provided with eclipse. Here's a great tutorial on how to use it:

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/ddms.html,

You can use it to get all kinds of information such as number of running threads, processes, memory allocation and usage and much more. Open it in eclipse and generate a heap dump to view it in eclipse memory analyzer.